# Class or Dictionary

Tags: c#, class, dictionary

I want to create a immutable `Scale` class in C#.

```
public sealed class Scale
{
    string _Name;
    string _Description;
    SomeOrderedCollection _ScaleValueDefinitions;
    Unit _Unit

    // properties
    ....
    // methods
    ContainsValue(double value)
    ....

    // constructors
    // all parameters except scalevaluedefinitions are optional
    // for a Scale to be useful atleast 1 ScaleValueDefinition should exist
    public Scale(string name, string description, SomeOrderedCollection scaleValueDefinitions, unit)
    { /* initialize */}
}
```

so first a `ScaleValueDefinition` should be represented by to values:

- Value (double)
- Definition (string)

these values are known before the Scale class is created and should be unique.
so what is the best approach.

1. create a immutable class ScaleValueDefinition with value and definition as properties and use it in a list.
2. use a dictionary.
3. use another way i didn't think of...

and how to implement it.
for option 1. i can use `params ScaleValueDefinition[] ValueDefinitions` in the constructor, but how to do it for the other options?

and as last at what amount of value's (properties) should i choose one option over the other?

Comment: For option 1, a `Tuple<double,string>` is an immutable type already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like this maybe?

```
public sealed class Scale<TUnit> : IReadOnlyList<TUnit>
{
    private readonly string name;
    private readonly string description;
    private readonly IList<TUnit> definition;

    public Scale(
             string name,
             string description,
             IEnumerable<TUnit> definition) : this(name, description)
    {
        this.definition = definition.ToList();
    }

    public Scale(
             string name,
             string description,
             params TUnit[] definition) : this(name, description)
    {
        this.definition = definition;
    }

    private Scale(
             string name,
             string description)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
    }


    public string Name
    {
        get { return this.name; }
    }

    public string Description
    {
        get { return this.description; }
    }

    public TUnit this[int index]
    {
        get { return this.definition[index]; }
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return this.definition.Count; )
    }

    public IEnumerator<TUnit> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.definition.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Comment: looks good. even when Unit isn't the class in the collection ScaleValueDefinition is. gonna try it out now.

Comment: I really like you answer. the only down side is that i still use vs2010. is there an alternative to IReadOnlyList?

Comment: @user2038134, it sounds dirty but the standard approach was to implement `IList` instead and throw `NotImplementedException`s on the members that you do not wish to support. There is a question and answer about it somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

It's rather opinion based but explicit classes seem to be better as they really express your intent. Also, code is easier to maintain - imagine changing keys of your dictionary all over the code, whereas for a class one place refactoring would suffice.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't mentioned whether you will need to look up definitions by their value, which of course is the main purpose of a dictionary. Otherwise, I don't see any reason to use a dictionary.

If you need to do lookups, I would actually use *both*: that is, a `Dictionary<double, ScaleValueDefinition>`. That way, I can look up the definitions by the value, but also retain a reference to the value I looked up. This also means the dictionary can be dynamically generated from a sequence of ScaleValueDefinitions (using [ToDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549277.aspx)), and the order of that sequence can be stored, without forcing the user to pass in an [OrderedDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.aspx):

```
private IEnumerable<ScaleValueDefinition> _internalOrderedCollection;
private Dictionary<double, ScaleValueDefinition> _internalDictionary;

public Scale(string name, string description, IEnumerable<ScaleValueDefinition> scaleValueDefinitions) {
    _name = name;
    _description = description;
    _internalOrderedCollection = scaleValueDefinitions.ToList();
    _internalDictionary = scaleValueDefinitions.ToDictionary(svd => svd.Value);
}
```

For immutability, you can simply wrap the internal dictionary in a public [ReadOnlyDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712875.aspx).

Comment: yes, it will be used to get a definitions based on a value. but why should i keep the `internalOrderedCollection` if my class is immutable.

Comment: @user2038134 I assumed you wanted to keep the order intact, since you had SomeOrderedCollection in your example code. The internal list would allow you to iterate the definitions in the same order they were passed in. It wouldn't be public, although you could expose a ReadOnlyCollection of it.

Comment: i think we have a different view on `SomeOrderedCollection`. what i meant with it was something like `SortedSet<t>` or `SortedList<tk,tv>`